# Can't specify 'long' and 'float' in declaration specifiers

Tags: c

In C , we use the datatypes `int`, `float`, `char`, `long`, `short`, `long int`, `long long int`, `double`, `long double`. 
Why can't we use `long float` and `long long long int`?

Comment: because the language doesn't define those types

Comment: Why do we have for long int and long long int. why cant we just have long alone. We use it if we wanted to use it to store a big number.

Comment: @Angus:- A long int is a signed integral type that is at least 32 bits, while a long long or long long int is a signed integral type is at least 64 bits. Also to add that long is equivalent to long int just as short and short int

Comment: @Angus You **can** do just `long` alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple you dont have `long float` and `long long long int` in C. The language designers [have not defined them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) to be used in C.

Also to add that long is equivalent to long int just like short and short int.

On most of the 32-bit platforms:

- int is specified as 32 bits
- long is specified as 32 bits as well
- long long is specified as 64 bits

On most of the 64-bit platforms:

- int is specified as 32 bits
- long is specified as either 32 or 64 bits
- long long is specified as 64 bits as well

On a side note

**long long** is not part of C89/CC90, nor part of C++98 or C++03, but does exist in C99 (and therefore in C11) and in C++11 (and therefore in C++14).

Answer (score 4):

Originally `long long int` was not in the language specification (`long int` was the largest signed integer type in C). Later `long long int` was introduced. Maybe one day we'll see `long long long int` in C language as well, but that day is yet to come.

As for `long float`... there is not much sense in it. The next larger floating-point type already has a name and it is called `double`. `long float` would be just like `long short` or `long char`.

Comment: Originally, `long int` was not in the language specification, though it was added fairly early on.

Comment: Suggest adding `long double`.

Answer (score 3):

At one time, `long float` was a synonym for `double`, but the C standard ruled it illegal.  There's an outside chance that a compiler in non-conforming mode would accept `long float` still.

You can't use `long long long int` because there is as yet no precedent implementing it (128-bit integer?) and because it would be extremely clumsy.

#### Archaeology

The first edition of K&R "The C Programming Language" published in 1978 has a version of "C Reference Manual" which does have `long` and explicitly mentions `long float` as one of the possible types.  However, the main text does not seem to mention `long float`.

Volume 2A of the UNIX™ Programmer's Manual for 7th Edition Unix is available online at [Bell Labs](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/); it was published as a whole in January 1979.  It has a version of "C Reference Manual" which makes no reference to the keyword `long`, and therefore does not recognize `long float`. (Note that although most chapters of Volume 2A are available separately, this chapter is not, but it is included in the PDF and Postscript versions made available via a link on the main page.  <s>Given that the separate chapter is not available for copyright reasons, I cannot formally rule out the possibility that the chapter in the composite Volume 2A PDF is actually an earlier edition of "C Reference Manual".</s> *Update:* I found my bound, printed, published version of UNIX Programmer's Manual Volume 2 (published 1983, ISBN 0-03-061743-X) and indeed, that chapter is preceded by 'This manual is reprinted, with minor changes, from *The C Programming Language*, by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, Prentice-Hall, Inc., 1978.'  It lists `long` as a keyword.  Therefore, the version available in the PDF is indeed from an older revision of the "C Reference Manual".  The older version is useful in that it substantiates my claim that `long` and hence `long float` were not always a part of the C language.)

The C language was in some flux in the period 1978-1979, therefore.  Structure assignment and passing and returning structures to functions was added a little later still, but well before the C89 standard.

Comment: Following the same history that lead to `long int` being 64-bit if not too expensive,  32-bit otherwise, `long long long int`, if it existed, would probably be 128-bit if not too expensive, 64-bit otherwise. Only `long long long long int` would be guaranteed to be 128-bit wide.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: since `long long int` is at least 64-bits, I think that a 'triple `long`' would have to be at least 128-bits, wouldn't it?

Comment: You are right, I got the progression wrong. Extrapolating from previous history, if processors on which 128-bit operations appeared, some compilers for these architectures would start mapping `long` to 64-bit and `long long` to 128-bit, and the committee would introduce `long long long` as a type that would guarantee at least 128-bit.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Another possible mapping for 128-bit processors would be: 8 = `signed char`; 16 = `short`; 32 = `int`; 64 = `long`; 128 = `long long`.  That would leave open the option of `intmax_t` being used for 256-bit integers with no extra names being introduced into the hierarchy.  (I don't think the standard says that '`int` shall be the same size as another type'.)  I would hope that the 'triple `long`' name would not be used; `int_least128_t` would be an obvious name to use, building on the precedents in `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

`long float` is essentially (and used to be a synonym for) a `double`. Adding extra `long`s to an integer type has to stop somewhere, and 64 bits is the compromise chosen (since it's generally directly representable on most processors).

Comment: `long float` is no longer a synonym for `double`, but it was once.  I suppose some compilers might still accept it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I meant in the more general sense, but I should clarify.